# Importing a function from a Class in another module

Tags: python, module

I am intending to import a function under a Class particle from another module (if that makes a difference) which is the first function you see, and another was from the current module.

I have initialised mass and velocity with self in the Class particle.

```
energy = particle.KE(self, mass, velocity) + pot_energy_dw(D, r, re, alpha)
```

However, I got this error. I have checked to see that I am using the right parameters, `KE(self, mass, velocity)`.

```
File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\velocityVerlet3D.py", line 128, in main
    energy = particle.KE(self, mass, velocity) + pot_energy_dw(D, r, re, alpha)

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: you don't need the `self` argument while calling class method, try this: `particle.KE(mass, velocity)`.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia shouldn't it be something like `particle().KE(mass, velocity)`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like

```
particle().KE(mass, velocity)
```

or

```
p = particle()        # an instance of the class `particle` 
p.KE(mass, velocity)  # call instance methods
```

`self` means a class instance. You call `particle.KE` if `KE` is a static/class method.

To call instance methods, you need to initiate the instance of a class, e.g., `particle()`. Then you can call them through the instance.